# Did Maurice Mearleau-Ponty really say this quote?

Tags: quote, authenticity, merleau-ponty

I found this quote in the book "At the Existentialist Cafe" by Sarah Bakewell, but I cannot find a confirmation of its authenticity anywhere else on the internet. Perhaps it's a unique translation?

> I am a psychological and historical structure. Along with existence, I received a way of existing, or a style. All of my actions and thoughts are related to this structure, and even a philosopher’s thought is merely a way of making explicit his hold upon the world, which is all he is. And Yet, I am free, not in spite of or beneath these motivations, but rather by their means. For that meaningful life, that particular signification of nature and history that I am, does not restrict my access to the world; it is rather my means of communication with it

The Phenomenology of Perception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the quote is indeed from the *Phenomenology of Perception*. It can be found on page 482 of the Landes translation published by Routledge in 2012. The same passage, in different translation, can be found on page 529 of the older Colin Smith translation:

> I am a psychological and historical structure, and have
>   received, with existence, a manner of existing, a style. All my actions
>   and thoughts stand in a relationship to this structure, and even a philosopher’s
>   thought is merely a way of making explicit his hold on the
>   world, and what he is. The fact remains that I am free, not in spite of, or
>   on the hither side of, these motivations, but by means of them.For this
>   significant life, this certain significance of nature and history which I
>   am, does not limit my access to the world, but on the contrary is
>   my means of entering into communication with it.